# Altering individual graphs in Pandas hist groupby plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm plotting a frequencies group by countries in an iPython notebook using:

```
df['country'].hist(by=df['frequency'], bins=yr_bins)
```

But the resultant figure is badly formatted;
[image: Badly_formattedhist]

Things I'd like/like to be able to define:

- y axis log or not
- sizing of individual graphs
- x axis limits
- auto layout
- spacing between each individual graph so the labels don't over lap

Things I've realised so far:

- the call to `.hist` outputs a 9x9 2d array of `matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot` objects
- all of these `AxesSubplots`s are embedded in a single figure

Answer (score 0):

Best working case so far:

- For log or not: just using keyword `log=True`
- Sizing of individual graphs and an auto layout:

  - Determine the number of groups: `n = len(df.groupby('country')`
  - Then use the combination of keywords `layout=(row, column)` and `figsize(width, height)`:

    - Hard code number of columns to `c`, and desired width `w` and height `h` ofeach graph
    - Then use `layout((n / c), c)` and `figsize=((c * w), (( (n/c) * h ))`

- Setting x axis limits: get the axes array by `axes = df...` then loop over the axes applying `set_xlim(lim)`

```
       for row in axes:
           for ax in row:
               ax.set_xlim(lim)
```

- The spacing turnout of but if required then do:

```
    plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.5, hspace=1)
```